# Single mangedQuery to scan multiple folders for audio files

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an ArrayList containing folder name which contains songs:

```
private ArrayList<String> searchableDir = new ArrayList<String>();
searchableDir.add("/mnt/sdcard/Tracks/U2/");
searchableDir.add("/mnt/sdcard/Tracks/Coldplay/");
```

Now I want to run a managed query that will fetch songs from both these folders.
Currently I'm only able to fetch one folder at a time:

```
String abc = "/mnt/sdcard/Tracks/U2/";
cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE \""
            + abc + "%\"", null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
            + " ASC");
```

Above query is working like:

```
select _id from audio where _data like "/mnt/sdcard/Tracks/U2/%";
```

But I want to make a single managedquery that will fetch tracks from all the folders in searchableDir arraylist.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use `managedQuery`... it's been deprecated for a pretty long time now. Use a `CursorLoader` instead.

Comment: `CursorLoader` is from API 11, but I also want to support 9 & 10.

Comment: It goes back to API 4 using the support package: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: I tried ur advice, but still how can it solve my problem?

Comment: @raul8 ..here I want to fetch audio files from individual folder..but it's not working...can u suggest me where I am doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 0):

use following to get all audio files available in sdcard :

> String[] STAR = { "*" };
>               Uri allaudiosong =
>   MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
>   String audioselection =
>   MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
>   Cursor cursor =
>   mContext.managedQuery(allaudiosong, STAR, audioselection, null, null);